# Frozen screen on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 19.10, 20.04

I have Ubuntu 19.10 LTS on an HP envy 17 notebook, and I recently upgraded my system to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. And one day while I'm working on it, the screen just froze! So I powered it off, then on; then when I put my password the screen becomes black! I added the `"nomodeset"` at the last of the variables line of `grub` (as I read online), and it didn't help at all, and now it's freezing at the logo of HP & UBUNTU.

[image]

Please help, I haven't found a case like mine if you could help me.

```
                 *** Quick Update***
```

I don't know how, but now the computer is giving me the ability to enter my password. But again the screen is black after entering my password.

Comment: You may have a BIOS problem, or some disk corruption. Can you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have commenting privileges yet, but I just wanted to mention that I too experienced a freeze just now after updating to 20.04. That is the first and only freeze I can remember in my many years of running Ubuntu. (I am able to login though.)